# Flat Modules and Localization at prime ideal

Tags: modules, localization, flatness

Suppose $M$ is a flat $A$ module and $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal in $A$, question is to prove that

> $M_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is a flat $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ module.

Let $S=R\setminus \mathfrak{p}$. Consider sequence of $S^{-1}A$ modules
$$0\rightarrow S^{-1}N_1\rightarrow S^{-1}N_2\rightarrow S^{-1}N_3\rightarrow 0.$$
We have to prove that we have exact sequence 
$$0\rightarrow S^{-1}N_1\otimes_{S^{-1}A}S^{-1}M\rightarrow S^{-1}N_2\otimes_{S^{-1}A}S^{-1}M\rightarrow S^{-1}N_3\otimes_{S^{-1}A}S^{-1}M\rightarrow 0.$$
As $S^{-1}(N\otimes_AM)\cong S^{-1}N\otimes_{S^{-1}A}S^{-1}M$ it suffices to prove that we have an exact sequence
$$0\rightarrow S^{-1}(N_1\otimes_AM)\rightarrow S^{-1}(N_2\otimes_AM)\rightarrow S^{-1}(N_3\otimes_AM)\rightarrow 0.$$

**To prove this, it suffices to prove that we have following exact sequence** 
$$0\rightarrow N_1\otimes_AM\rightarrow N_2\otimes_AM\rightarrow N_3\otimes_AM\rightarrow 0.$$

Then, as localization preserves exactness we would have the sequences that we have desired. **This is definitely more than what we want**.

Suppose we have $$0\rightarrow N_1\rightarrow N_2\rightarrow N_3\rightarrow 0$$
 and not just $$0\rightarrow S^{-1}N_1\rightarrow S^{-1}N_2\rightarrow S^{-1}N_3\rightarrow 0.$$ **This is definitely more than what we have.**

As $M$ is a flat $A$ module $$0\rightarrow N_1\rightarrow N_2\rightarrow N_3\rightarrow 0$$ implies we have an exact sequence 
$$0\rightarrow N_1\otimes_AM\rightarrow N_2\otimes_AM\rightarrow N_3\otimes_AM\rightarrow 0$$ and we are done.

I am not able to solve this. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You're just forgetting that if $N$ is an $S^{-1}A$-module, $S^{-1}N\simeq N$ as  $S^{-1}A$-module.

Comment: I understand that if $N$ is an $S^{-1}A$ module then $S^{-1}N\cong N$ as $S^{-1}A$ module but I do not see how it is relevant here.. My $N_i$ are $A$ modules.. @Bernard

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take it from this point of view: consider an exact sequence of $S^{-1}A$-modules:
$$0\longrightarrow N_1\longrightarrow N_2\longrightarrow N_3\longrightarrow 0  $$
and tensor by  $S^{-1}M$ over $S^{-1}A$: the sequence: 
$$0\longrightarrow N_1\otimes_{S^{-1}A}S^{-1}M\longrightarrow N_2\otimes_{S^{-1}A}S^{-1}M\longrightarrow N_3\otimes_{S^{-1}A}S^{-1}M\longrightarrow 0  $$remains exact because
$$N_i\otimes_{S^{-1}A}S^{-1}M\simeq N_i\otimes_{S^{-1}A}(S^{-1}A\otimes_{A}M)\simeq (N_i\otimes_{S^{-1}A}S^{-1}A)\otimes_{A}M\simeq N_i\otimes_{A}M, $$
and $N$ is $A$-flat.

Comment: How to make sure that the maps $f_i\otimes\text{id}$ in the sequence of $S^{-1}A$-modules coincide with those $f_i$ $(N_i\overset{f_i}{\to}N_{i+1})$ in the sequence of $A$-modules?